# How to justify anonymous clusters?

Tags: clustering, sampling, cluster-sample

Is there a reasonable situation where the clusters are anonymous?
What I mean is that one can ensure the subjects sampled are from the same cluster, but she does not know exactly which cluster they are in.
An artificial case is that the researcher knows males and females are encoded using odd and even numbers, respectively. But she does not know whether males correspond to odd or even numbers. However, by drawing only subjects with odd or even numbers, she can ensure they are of the same gender. I was wondering whether there are more natural cases. Thank you very much!

Comment: It's not clear what exactly is a problem here. If you had anonymous labels for males and females in most cases you could fairly easily guess the true labels from contextual information. That is why “anonymizing” data by replacing the labels with something else doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

A very common case similar to your description will be a Randomized Controlled Study where the statistician is blinded, I.e. that information is withhold intentionally from her.

However the term "cluster" often refers to unsupervised learning which is a totally different thing then gender or randomization. There it is normal to get cluster and then have to find out, what properties define chances to be in a cluster.